# Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'tabs')

Tags: reactjs, google-chrome-extension

I'm attempting to build a chrome extension that will grab the current url when tabBtn is clicked. I am receiving an error message`Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'tabs')` I've used this method `chrome.browser.tabs.query({currentWindow: true,active: true },(tabs) => {})` in vanilla JS without any issues but using React its not working. I've tried placing the above code in `useEffect()` but the error is unresolved. I've tried examples from this [article](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-call-web-apis-with-the-useeffect-hook-in-react) and this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70164890/chrome-extension-uncaught-type-error-cannot-read-properties-of-undefined-read) which was unfortunately resolved.

*** error message now read `Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'query')`

```
/*global chrome*/

import {useEffect, useState} from 'react';
import {TabBtn} from "./components/Buttons"


function App() {
 
 
/*  useEffect(()=>{ 
      chrome.tabs.query(
         { currentWindow: true, active: true },
         (tabs) => {
           // setMyLeads((prev) => [...prev, 
         tabs[0].url]);
           console.log(tabs[0].url);
         }
       );
    
  },[]) */


  const tabBtn = () => {
       chrome.tabs.query(
         { currentWindow: true, active: true },
         (tabs) => {
        
           console.log(tabs[0].url);
         }
       );
  }

 
  return (
    <main>
    
      <TabBtn tabBtn={tabBtn} />

    </main>
  );
}

export default App
```

manifest.json

```
{
    "name": "chrome extension app",
    "version": "1.0",
    "manifest_version": 3,
     "permissions": [
        "activeTab",
        "storage",
        "tabs"
    ],
    "action": {
        "default_popup": "index.html"
    },
    "default_icon": "/img/icon.png"
}
```

Comment: Remove `browser.`

Comment: I'm now getting error message 'Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'query')'

Comment: I guess you open your page from localhost or file: URL. You should click the extension icon in toolbar. Also note that the popup is a separate window so it has its own separate devtools.

Comment: In google chrome extension I'm now receiving this  error 'Uncaught TypeError: window.chrome.query is not a function'

Comment: There's no such thing as window.chrome.query. Use `chrome.tabs.query`.

Comment: that's why i'm confused. I have ```chrome.tabs.query``` in the code. i'm searching google to try and figure out why it's throwing this error.

Comment: You probably look at an old error. Use the popup's devtools as explained above.

Comment: It's working! Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I got into the same situation today. It turns out that `chrome.tabs.query` cannot be used in the content script. The doc:

- [Chrome Extension chrome.tabs documentation](https://developer.chrome.com/docs/extensions/reference/tabs/)

says `Additionally, content scripts cannot use tabs.query`.

Alternatively, if you want to achieve this, you can send a message in the content script:

```js
document.onmouseup = function() {
  chrome.runtime.sendMessage({msgType: "queryTabId"}, function(response) {
    var _tabId = response.tabId;
    console.log('current tab id:' + _tabId);
    if(_tabId){
      var _SELECTION = {_tabId: ''};
      _SELECTION._tabId = window.getSelection()?.toString() ?? '';
      chrome.storage.local.set(_SELECTION, function() {
          console.log('Selection saved: ', _SELECTION._tabId);
      });
    }
  })
```

and query tab id in `background.js`:

```js
chrome.runtime.onMessage.addListener((message, sender, sendResponse) => {
  console.log("background received message: " + message);
  if (message.msgType === 'queryTabId') {
    chrome.tabs.query({active: true, currentWindow: true}, function(tabs) {
      sendResponse({tabId: tabs[0].id});
    });
  }
  // https://stackoverflow.com/a/56483156/9304616
  return true;
});
```

The example is a little more complex than your need, but the basic requirement is satisfied.